# Laravel - User Access denied

Tags: php, laravel, database

I created my first App, using Laravel in the Backend. Everything was running on my localhost and I deployed everything to my Netcup Webhosting Server.

I run composer install successfully, generated the API key by using `php artisan key:generate --ansi` and set up my .env file. The File looks like:

```
APP_NAME="App Name"
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64_key
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://xx.xxxxx.de

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME="db_user"
DB_PASSWORD="db_user_password"
```

The I want to create all the database tables by using `php artisan migrate`. I tripple checked the values set in the .env and red a lot of solutions of other posts, but nothing worked. I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I already added quotes to DB_User and Pasword in .env file. I restarted the server several times and cleaned the cache.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for netcup webhosting support

Comment: @N69S Thanks for this hint. I contacted the Netcup Support. Nonetheless I would keep this open for others having the same issue.

Comment: There is no need to keep this question open since it doesn't provide any solution other than "contact support". Unless you add an answer that fixed your issue with enough details so other contributors may benefit from it, I suggest you delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some problems with auth on the Netcup Web hosting Server. Can you check list of user with access to db_name? Besides, by screenshoot I guessing that hosting add prefix ("k177581_") for db_name and db_user

Comment: I also tripple checked, that the user has full access.
The prefix indeed is added, but I also added the prefix in the .env file

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

As @N69S correctly suggested it was related to Netcup. For any other Netcup user the following solution.
Netcup devides its Webhosting and Database. Therefore you need to put you Database IP into your .env file. That can be found in the connection data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).